Integration of multivariate function in Score Matching
I'm studying this note about score matching. Here we have some samples from an unknown probability function $p_{data}(x)$ and want to represent it as a parametrized function $p_\theta(x)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta$ is the set of parameters.
The objective is to minimize the Fisher divergence between these two functions.
$$
\theta^{*} = \arg \min_\theta \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}\big[|| \nabla_x \log p_{data}(x) - \nabla_x p_\theta (x) ||^2\big]
$$
For simplifying this, we can write the above divergence as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int || \nabla_x \log p_{data}(x)||^2 p_{data}(x)dx -\int \nabla_x p_{data}(x) \nabla_x\log p_\theta (x)dx + \frac{1}{2}\int || \nabla_x \log p_\theta(x)||^2 p_{data}(x)dx
$$
The first term is a constant and the last term is $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}\big[\frac{1}{2} || \nabla_x \log p_\theta(x)||^2 \big]$.
The final result is:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}\big[\frac{1}{2} || \nabla_x \log p_\theta(x)||^2 + \text{tr}\big(\nabla_x^2 \log p_\theta (x)\big) \big] + \text{const.}
$$
How to derive $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}} \big[\text{tr}\big(\nabla_x^2 \log p_\theta (x)\big)\big]$ from $-\int \nabla_x p_{data}(x) \nabla_x\log p_\theta (x)dx$? I could do it for 1D case. With integration by parts $\int f'g = fg - \int g'f$ and setting $f'=\nabla_x p_{data}(x)$ and $g=\nabla_x\log p_\theta (x)$, we have:
$$
-\int \nabla_x p_{data}(x) \nabla_x\log p_\theta (x)dx =
-p_{data}(x) \nabla_x\log p_\theta (x)|_{x=-\infty}^\infty + \int \nabla_x^2 \log p_\theta (x) p_{data} (x)dx
$$
By assuming $p_{data}(x) \nabla_x\log p_\theta (x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow -\infty$, which is not a bad assumption, the result would be $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}} \big[\nabla_x^2 \log p_\theta (x)\big]$, which is correct.
But I didn't understand the multivariate version.
Thanks for your response!

If you start with a multivariate integral
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\log p_m(x;\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \log p_d(x) dx_1 \ldots dx_n.
$$
you can isolate one particular integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\log p_m(x;\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \log p_d(x) dx_i
$$
which you can do using univariate integration by parts. Then you get the result shown in the note you reference.

So the big idea is $$\int f(x)dx = \sum_{i=1}^n \int ... \int f(x)_i dx_1 ... dx_n$$ for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Right?
